# Multiple Kinects in Rviz, image fusion?

Tags: kinect, rviz, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Currently I've got three Kinects (1473's) running on Ubuntu 12.04 with ROSHydro.  I'm able to access all image streams from all three Kinects, and the next step I wanted to achieve was combining streams to create a three dimensional (or at least partially 3D) image in something like RViz.  I know that I need to create a transform between them but I can't find any tutorials or similar questions on here.  Can someone help or point me in the right direction?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/100816/multiple-kinects-in-rviz,-image-fusion?/) by [Athoesen](https://answers.ros.org/users/8296/athoesen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 429 on 2013-11-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [camera_pose_calibration](http://wiki.ros.org/camera_pose_calibration) package essentially provides exactly what you´re looking for. Haven´t used it myself, so not sure how mature and easy to adapt it is. The [calibration](http://wiki.ros.org/calibration) package also is able to estimate transforms, but is originally meant for robot kinematic calibration. Based on it, a [approach using the Google Ceres solver](http://www.willowgarage.com/blog/2013/08/09/enabling-robots-see-better-through-improved-camera-calibration) is also available.
There are of course also other options, like registration using some PCL tools (if you have significant point cloud overlap), using AR markers visible in multiple views and others, which likely require some more work on your part.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2013-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Athoesen](https://answers.ros.org/users/8296/athoesen/) on 2014-01-09**:
I appears that the package does not work straight from getting it but there is a github fork which may resolve problems.